# Russell's paradox: a set cannot contain its own powerset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been trying to challenge myself but with no luck. Maybe one of you will have a better idea.
How can it be proven that there can't be a set which contains its own powerset, using only russell's paradox?
I've managed to prove it with other principles or axioms, such as that a set can not belong to itself, or that a powerset cannot belong to itself.

Comment: since when is russell's paradox a principle?

Comment: @user251257 thanks, the question has been edited

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "no other mathematical principle".  I'm also not sure what you mean by using Russell's paradox — maybe an example would help?

Comment: @ErickWong. let's assume that there's an infinite set which contains its own powerset. meaning every subset in P(A) must also belong to A. Is it possible to disprove this claim by showing that the existence of such a set will also mean that an x will belong to set A only if it doesn't belong to set A?

Comment: It is a direct contradiction to axiom of regularity ... what do you have in mind about russell's paradox?

Comment: @user251257 look at what I wrote in the comment above yours :)

Comment: Do you know what the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) is?  @user251257 has already answered your previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDIT: Borrowing from Noah)

Suppose to the contrary that for set $A$, we have $P(A)\subset A$.

Now, by an axiom of set theory, there exists a subset $B\subset A$ such that $\forall a:[a\in B\iff a\in A \land a\notin a]$.

Since $B\subset A$ and $P(a) \subset A$, we must have $B\in A$.

Along the lines of RP, we obtain the contradiction $B\in B\iff B\notin B$, thus negating our initial assumption.

See my machine-verified [formal proof](http://www.dcproof.com/PowerSetNotSubset.htm) (updated).

---

Perhaps more intuitively satisfying  (without $a\notin a$ and such) would be:

If   $X \subset Y$ then there exists the obvious injection $f:X \to Y$, i.e. $f(x)=x$. And, for any set $S$, there cannot exist an injection $f :P(S)\to S$. So, we cannot have $P(S)\subset S$.

Answer (score 6):

It is more complicated than necessary.

Let $A$ be a set with $P(A)\subseteq A$. Then, let $B = \{ S \in A \mid S\notin S \}$. That is in fact a set by axiom schema of specification.

Now, notice that from $B \subseteq A$ follows $B\in P(A) \subseteq A$.
If $B\in B$, then we have $B\notin B$. If $B\notin B$, then we have $B\in B$. Just like in the Russell's Paradox.

*Note:*

For sake of completeness, here is the contradiction to regularity:
$$ A\in P(A) \subseteq A. $$

Comment: For further completeness, I note that this critically depends on the comprehension scheme available. There are theories whose axioms don't guarantee the existence of $\{S\in A|S\notin S\}$ and similar sets, in which you can end up with $\mathcal{P}(A)=A$.

Comment: @Abdel. I think the OP asks whether we can prove  that if $P(X)$ exists then $P(X)\not \in X$ without any set-theory axioms, just as Russell's Paradox is proved : $[\;\exists X\;\forall Y \;(Y\in X\iff Y\not \in Y)) \;]\implies \exists X\;(X\in X\land X \not  \in X)$ without any additional assumptions.

Comment: I don't see how this proves anything about power sets. You can conclude that $B\notin A$ from the above construction, but not much else. Can't comment on the bit about regularity.

Comment: @DanChristensen I don't see the problem. By definition, $B\subseteq A$. Assuming $P(A)\subseteq A$, we have that $B\in P(A)$, so $B\in A$. But then (by definition of $B$, using the fact that $B\in A$) we have $B\in B$ iff $B\not\in B$. This is a contradiction, so our assumption that $P(A)\subseteq A$ must be false. So this seems completely right to me. Or am I missing something?

Comment: To add to Malice Vidrine's comment, the theory New Foundations (NF) is one theory in which $P(A)\subseteq A$ can happen.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for clearing that up somewhat, but I think you left out some key points.

Comment: @DanChristensen Such as what? I don't see where I left anything out.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The contradiction $B\in A$ and $B\notin A$.

Comment: @DanChristensen That's not how the argument needs to go. In my comment, and in the answer, we get $B\in A$ since $B\subseteq A$, and then directly conclude a la Russell that $B\in B\iff B\not\in B$. This is completely airtight; I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @DanChristensen that isn't true.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Perhaps I missed some subtlety in your argument, but the contradiction $B\in B \iff B \notin B$ only gets you $B\notin A$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You need to obtain a second contradiction, $B\in A$ and $B\notin A$, to obtain the final result. Maybe I am being too picky, but such a key point should probably be made more explicit.

Comment: @DanChristensen No, that's not correct. We **assume** $P(A)\subseteq A$ for contradiction. We then *prove* $B\in A$, and from that *prove* that $B\in B\iff B\not\in B$; this means our **assumption**, $P(A)\subseteq A$, was false. There's no need to do anything else; this is just straight proof by contradiction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber For what it is worth, here is my machine-verified formal proof at http://www.dcproof.com/PowerSetNotSubset.htm . Note the two contradictions on lines 25 and 42. Enjoy!

Comment: @DanChristensen I'm not saying you *can't* do two contradictions, I'm saying you don't *need* to. Do you understand that?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand what you mean, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: @DanChristensen What step of the proof that's been given do you doubt? Assume for contradiction that $P(A)\subseteq A$. Let $B=\{a\in A: a\not\in a\}$. By definition, $B\subseteq A$, so - by our assumption for contradiction - $B\in A$. But then (since by definition of $B$, for all $x\in A$ we have $x\in B\iff x\not\in x$) we have $B\in B\iff B\not\in B$; contradiction, so our assumption was incorrect - that is, $P(A)\not\subseteq A$. Exactly what part of this isn't clear?

Comment: @DanChristensen Seriously? Wow. OK, I'm done here. Let me know if you have an *actual* objection.

Comment: @NoahSchweber How about this: In your second to last sentence, I think you have identified incorrect assumption to be negated. Maybe you got confused by the set-builder notation in your definition of $B$. I use $\forall x:[ x\in B \iff x \in A \land x\notin x$]. You can only get $B\in B\iff B\notin B$ by first assuming that $B\in A$. That is the assumption you should be negating at that point.

Comment: @DanChristensen "$B\in A$" doesn't need to be separately assumed: it *follows immediately* from the fact that $B\subseteq A$ (by definition), together with the **assumption** that $P(A)\subseteq A$. I'm not getting confused by set-builder notation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Right you are. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a power set is generated by subsets of the given set. So you can make a cardinality argument.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which specifies that they're looking for an answer using (the reasoning behind) Russell's paradox.